# Fullpage.js - Enable vertical scrolling inside non-fullpage modal

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js, vertical-scrolling

I have a modal element that should not be part of the *fullpage.js* scrolling. All the main containers are fixed positioned.

I can't manage to get scrolling to work inside this modal.

I've tried setting '**normalScrollElements**' and '**fixedElements**', and '**setAllowScrolling**'.

None of those options do the trick. Does anyone know how to fix or had the same issue?

How do I release the scroll event while this other modal is open?

I have tried non-fixed elements and moving them out of "#fullpage" as well, *fullpage.js* stays hooked on the scroll events.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I've searched on here but seemingly no solutions.

Thanks in advance :)

My config looks like this:

```
fitToSection: true,
fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
scrollBar: true,
loopHorizontal: true,
scrollHorizontally: true,
resetSliders: true,
scrollOverflow: true,
scrollOverflowReset: true,
scrollOverflowOptions: null,
touchSensitivity: 33,
controlArrows: true,
verticalCentered: false,
normalScrollElements: '#menu',
fixedElements: '#header, #footer',
sectionSelector: '.js-fullpage-section',
slideSelector: '.js-full-page-slide'
```

What plugin author suggested doing on modal open/close - Doesn't work:

```
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false/true);
```

My HTML structure:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- Sticky header HTML -->
    </div>
    <div id="pages">
        <!-- Fullpage.js HTML -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Sticky footer HTML -->
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <!-- Hidden sticky modal I want to be able to scroll normally in when shown -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Difficult to help you unless you provide an isolated reproduction of the issue in jsfiddle or codepen.
`setAllowScrolling` should work in **all cases**, as it completely removes the scroll wheel detection of fullpage.js, leaving it free.

Comment: @Alvaro I eventually got it working with `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up, down');`, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what combination eventually fixed it, but `normalScrollElements: '#menu'` and `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up, down');` works.